# Why am I getting this Internal Server Error in the Laravel Framework?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have come across a situation that doesn't make much sense to me.  Just as some background information, I'm using the Laravel framework.  The page in question calls a query when the page is requested using Laravel's '->with('var', $array)' syntax.  This query (which I will post later) works perfectly fine on page load, and successfully inserts dummy data I fed it.

I call this same query via an Ajax $.post using jQuery, on click of a button.  However, when I do this $.post and call this query, I get an Internal Server Error every time.  Everything is exactly the same, information passed included; the only difference seems to be whether or not it is called on page load or via the $.post.

Here is the error:

[image]

**Below is the code that performs the query on page load:**

`routes.php` sends the HTTP get request to a file called `AppController.php`

**routes.php**
[image]
**AppController.php**
[image]

The page is then made with the following array acquired from `DeviceCheckoutController.php`

[image]

Which then goes to `DeviceCheckout.php`

[image]

I am able to echo $test on the page, and it returns the ID of a new row every time the page is reloaded (which obviously mean the 'insertGetId' query worked).  However, I hooked this query up to the page load just to test.  What I really want to happen is on click of a button.  Here is the code for that:

```
$("#checkoutFormbox").on('click', '#checkoutButton', function() {

        var checkoutInformation = Object();
        var accessories = [];
        var counter = 0;
        var deviceName = checkoutDeviceTable.cell(0, 0).data();

        $(".accessoryCheckbox").each(function() {
            //add accessory ID's to this list of only accessories selected to be checked out
            if($(this).val() == "1")
            {
                accessories[counter] = $(this).data('id') + " ";
            }
            counter++;
        });

        checkoutInformation['deviceID'] = $(".removeButton").val(); //deviceID was previously stored in the remove button's value when the add button was clicked
        checkoutInformation['outBy'] = '';
        checkoutInformation['outNotes'] = $("#checkOutDeviceNotes").val();
        checkoutInformation['idOfAccessories'] = 2;
        checkoutInformation['dueDate'] = $("#dueDate").val();

        if($("#studentIdButton").hasClass('active'))
        {
            checkoutInformation['renterID'] = 0;
            checkoutInformation['emplid'] = 1778884;
            console.log(checkoutInformation);
            $.post("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/testing/public/apps/devicecheckout-checkoutdevices", {type: "checkoutDeviceForStudent", checkoutInformation: checkoutInformation}, function(returnedData) {
                alert(returnedData);
            });
        }
});
```

Which is also then routed to `AppController.php`, specifically to the 'checkoutDeviceForStudent' part of the switch statement:

[image]

And then back to that query that is shown previously in `DeviceCheckout.php`

Finally, here is my DB structure for reference:

[image]

Any explanation as for why this would be happening?  Also, any Laravel or other general best practice tips would be greatly appreciated as I'm inexperienced in usage of this framework and programming overall.

Sorry for such a long post, I hope there is enough information to diagnose this problem.  Let me know if I need to include anything else.

Edit:  Included picture of error at the top of the page.

Comment: After all that, you need to include what the error actually is!

Comment: If you want an explanation, look into the webserver log why he throws a HTTP 500.

Comment: What do the server side error logs show? Don't show us pictures of code, copy and paste the actual code.

Comment: In `app/config/app.php` set `debug` as `true`. So you can see the error and we can help you.

Comment: A picture of the error should be at the top of page now.  Sorry about that.  Also, I do have debug set to true but it doesn't throw an error because (as far as I know), it can't when the Laravel query is called via Ajax.

Comment: "routes.php **sends the HTTP get request** to a file called AppController.php" ..but your console says you're making a `POST` request.  Can you post your route as well?

Comment: Absolutely, hold on while I add that in.

Edit: c-griffin, sorry for the misunderstanding, the text you quoted is for when the query is loaded on page load, with the Laravel 'View::make('view.folder.viewFile', DeviceCheckoutController::varsToViewCheckoutDevices());'.  This calls the query on page load, but I don't want it to do that.  I just did that for testing purposes, the desired behavior is to call the query via the POST, which is what is giving me an error.

Comment: @Quentin Strangely enough, the server log at <code>var/log/apache2/error.log</code> shows no mention of a POST Internal Servor error.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution to my problem after some advice from a friend; much easier than I anticipated and much easier than any solution that has been offered to me here or other places.

Essentially, what I needed to do was place a  **try, catch**  clause in my model function, and then if an exception is encountered I store that in a variable, `return` it, and use `console.log()` to view the exception.  Here is an example to emulate my point:

```
public function getUserFullname($userID)
{
    try
    {
        $myResult = DB::connection('myDatabase')->table('TheCoolestTable')->select('fullName')->where('userID', '=', $userID)->get();

        return $myResult;  
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $errorMessage = 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage();

        return $errorMessage;
    }
}
```

And then on the View (or wherever your model function returns to), simply `console.log()` the output of your POST.  This will display the results of the successful query, or the results of the Exception if it encountered one as opposed to an unhelpful Internal Server Error 500 message.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is exactly the same, information passed included

No, it isn't.  If it was exactly the same you wouldn't be getting the error you're getting.

These sorts of issues are too difficult to solve by taking guesses at what the problem might be.  You need to

1. Setup your system so Laravel's logging errors to the laravel.log file
2. Setup you PHP system so errors Laravel can't handled are logged to your webserver's error log (and/or PHP's error log)
3. Put Laravel in debug mode so errors are output the the screen, and the view the output of your ajax request via Firebug or Chrome

Once you have the actual PHP error it's usually pretty easy to see what's different about the request you think is the same, and address the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have reviewed my laravel.log file, and found only references to undefined variables which threw errors and were fixed, nothing relating to any POST request errors I've encountered.  I have also checked my /var/log/apache2/access.log file.  This yielded different results; it did in fact show my POST request, and that it returned a 500 error, but that was it.  Here is what I found in the logs for reference:

Comment: [25/Aug/2014:18:16:00 +0000] "POST /testing/public/apps/devicecheckout-checkoutdevices HTTP/1.1" 500 833 "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/staffportal/public/apps/devicecheckout-checkoutdevices" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36" Also, I wasn't able to find my PHP error log.  Am I looking in the right places?  What log files should I be looking for?  Also, Laravel is set up in debug mode but it doesn't throw an error when I call the POST via jQuery.

Comment: That's your Apache access log, you want the apache error log.  You also want to tail these logs and watch the errors that come in when you make a request.

Comment: Gotcha.  In my Apache2 config file, I changed the error logging directory `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` to `/var/log/error.log`, which now shows up in the proper folder (note I also restarted Apache after making this change).  However, I've received the POST 500 error multiple times since setting this up and it isn't showing up in the `error.log` file.  The only thing that shows up is this: `Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u12 configured -- resuming normal operations`.  How can I properly configure it so it catches the POST errors?

Comment: A StackExchange comment thread probably isn't the best/easiest way to debugging server setup problems.