# Wildcards and Like on Laravel Error not working on $variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, wildcard

So I have this code

```
$Input    = Input::all();
$makethis = Input::flash();
$soptions = Input::get('soptions');

$items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=',Input::get('sex'))
                 ->where('bname', 'LIKE', '%$soptions%')
                 ->paginate(6);
```

What I want to do is for laravel to accept the value inside the `$soptions`. When I tried hard coding the `$soptions` it works fine.

One more question

```
$Input    = Input::all();
$makethis = Input::flash();
$textbox  = Input::get('searchbox');
$soptions = Input::get('soptions');

var_dump($soptions);

$items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=', Input::get('sex'))
                 ->where($soptions, 'LIKE', "$textbox")
                 ->paginate(6);

return View::make('gamefarms/index', compact('items','makethis'));
```

Now what I want to do is use the variable `$soptions` to be the query's field name, I get an error 500 when I do this

Comment: Use double quotes, not single quotes. Or concatenate.

Comment: If you have a second question it would be better to post a new question on the site.

Comment: Yes i know that, but i really need to fix this now. I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `'%$soptions%'` does not get interpolated, instead you should write `"%$soptions%"` or `"%{$soptions}%"` or `'%' . $soptions . '%'`. Simple mistake.

Comment: can you do this on my given code? cause i tried it and non of this is working

Comment: 1 - what `var_dump($soptions);` gives you? 2 - what is `var_dump(Input::get('sex'));`? 3 - error 500 is not enough, what stacktrace or logs are saying? If you dont know how to debug, please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489011/why-am-i-getting-this-internal-server-error-in-the-laravel-framework. Only you can make this happen.